# Powering from a circuit and controlling it at the same time

Tags: arduino, power-supply, power, relay

I have 24v AC coming from a door bell to its switch. I have removed this switch and using a relay to control it from my Arduino (MKR1000). This works fine.

However I do not want the Arduino to be battery powered. Instead I want to use the same 24v AC, step it down to 5v DC and power the Arduino from it. I can't get my head around this. Is this even possible to be powered from a circuit and control that circuit at the same time? If you can please briefly describe the circuit which can make this possible?

Comment: Kashif, do you have access to the 24v AC transformer? I am assuming that this is an isolated transformer that accepts mains power (120v or 220v AC) and steps it down to 24v AC - if so, what you propose should be possible, as DoxyLover suggests.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't have access to the transformer.

Comment: Do you happen to know how much current the door bell requires to operate and about how long you would intend that the Arduino would have to apply the 24VAC to the door bell? There are a couple of relatively simple ideas coming to mind, but I need to know those two bits, plus perhaps about how much current your Arduino requires (my idea would add another 5mA to that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not easily if all you have is the two wires that the switch/relay control. This is because:

1. The power you consume must come through the door bell. This greatly limits the amount of power you can use.
2. As soon as the relay closes, the input to your power supply goes to 0 volts as it is shorted out by the relay.

Assuming you don't need too much power and the relay doesn't need to be held closed too long or too often, you can design a power supply with large capacitors to keep the voltage up.

Your better bet is to run an additional wire from the transformer.

Comment: If the relay is on the high side he might get away with a ground wire, which might be lying around.

Comment: Edited my question to show that the incoming 24v is AC.

Comment: @Kashif I assumed it was 24VAC. My answer still applies.

Comment: @VladimirCravero The output of the transformer is probably isolated from the house ground. While he could connect one side of the secondary to ground, I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: And why would you leave it floating?